# WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: web-services, websocket, yii-extensions, pusher, phpwebsocket

I am using `Yii` framework and `OpenTok` `API` integrated with `PUSHER API`. When i tired to create an instance of `PUSHER` event, the connection established. But few seconds later, the connection closes automatically and give error like :**Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{}}.** I am trying pusher library version **1.11.2** and **1.12** as well (but at the same time) for testing.

**Console Logs:**

```
Pusher : State changed : initialized -> connecting
    Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://ws.pusherapp.com/app/?protocol=5&amp;client=js&amp;version=1.1....
    Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected
    Pusher : State changed : connecting -> disconnected
```

I have checked telnet ws.pusherapp.com 443,80 and 843 but what i am getting is Connection closed by foreign host.

Is there any method or something that i have lacking to debug or to test ?? Need some help to avoid that warning.

I have using

> chrome Version 23.0.1271.97
>
> Ubuntu 12.04
>
> Firefox 18.0

Comment: The URL here suggests that you did not have your `APP_KEY` set, or had it set to the empty string. (Normally, the `APP_KEY` value follows `app/` in the URL.)